# PHP 7, Apache 2.4, and Windows 10 aren't launching html files from htdocs

Tags: php, html

When I launch a .php file from Apache 24/htdocs, it works properly by using http:/localhost/example.php.

```
<?php $roll = rand(1,6);
echo "<p>This should show a diceroll:</p>";
echo 'Your roll is ' . $roll;  
?>
```

When I try to launch an .html file with php code in it the same way (http:/localhost/example.html), it "downloads" a copy of the file to my C:/Users/Rich/Downloads folder and runs it there, so the php scripts don't get executed, and and paths to other files in the html file can't be found.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Roll the Dice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This should show a diceroll.</p>
    <p><? php  
        $roll=rand(1,6);
        echo 'You rolled a '.$roll;        
        ?>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I just recently had to upgrade from Apache 2.2 and PHP 5, because suddenly none of my previously functioning html files with php worked. I'd get 404 errors when trying to run them. I assume something happened in a Windows 10 update to scramble my previous setup. So I updated Apache and PHP, tweaked everything until the .php files worked like they should, but I haven't figured out what's causing this weird behavior with the html files. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: PHP code will only be run if the file extension is `.php` ... unless you made a config change to make this work

Comment: Thanks, RiggsFolly. I must have been misremembering about being able to launch html files in php. - superpug